# Mostrar imagen desde base de datos remota, con JSOn. Android

Tags: android, json

En un RecyclerView muestro una lista de datos con imagen, esto proviene de una base de datos que tengo en 000webhost, donde ahí almaceno en una carpeta Images, las imágenes, archivos PHP y la tabla negocio con su respectivos nombre,categoría,descripción y ruta_imagen de los negocios.

El siguiente código es de el activity con el recycler:

```
 private void cargarwebservice() {
        progreso = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progreso.setMessage("Consultando...");
        progreso.show();
        String ip = getString(R.string.ip);
        String url = ip + "/DBRemota/wsJSONConsultarNegocio.php?categoria=" + categoria;
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
       // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        progreso.hide();
        Toast.makeText(this,"No se pudo consultar....." + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("ERROR" , error.toString());
        progreso.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        negocio negocio=null;

        JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("negocio");

        try {

            for (int i=0; i<json.length(); i++){
                Toast.makeText(this,json.length() + "" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                negocio=new negocio();
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);

                negocio.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("nombre"));  //NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO PHP
                negocio.setCategoria(jsonObject.optString("categoria"));
                negocio.setDescripcion(jsonObject.optString("descripcion"));
                negocio.setRutaimagen(jsonObject.optString("ruta_imagen"));
                negocio.setDireccion(jsonObject.optString("direccion"));
                negocio.setHorario(jsonObject.optString("horario"));

                listanegocio.add(negocio);

            }
            Toast.makeText(this,listanegocio.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progreso.hide();
            listanegocioadapter adapter=new listanegocioadapter(listanegocio,getApplicationContext());   //CREAR RECYCLER
            adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {        //METODO ON CLICK DE LA LISTA MANDO lista PARA EL DETALLE
                    negocio Negocio = listanegocio.get(recyclernegocio.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Listanegocio.this, Listanegociodetalle.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("negocio",Negocio);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            recyclernegocio.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha podido establecer conexión con el servidor" +
                    " "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progreso.hide();
        }
```

Y la clase listanegocioadapter:

```
public class listanegocioadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<listanegocioadapter.UsuariosHolder>
    implements View.OnClickListener {



        List<negocio> listaUsuarios;
       // RequestQueue request;
        Context context;
        private View.OnClickListener listener;


        public listanegocioadapter(List<negocio> listaUsuarios, Context context) {
            this.listaUsuarios = listaUsuarios;
            this.context = context;
            //request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);   //HACER LA TRANSFORMACION A LA IMAGEN
        }

        @Override
        public UsuariosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View vista= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.negocio_list,parent,false);
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            vista.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            vista.setOnClickListener(this);

            return new UsuariosHolder(vista);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(UsuariosHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.txtnombre.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getNombre());
            holder.txtcategoria.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getCategoria());
            holder.txtdescripcion.setText(listaUsuarios.get(position).getDescripcion());



            if (listaUsuarios.get(position).getRutaimagen()!=null){
                cargarImagenWebService(listaUsuarios.get(position).getRutaimagen(),holder);

            }else{
                holder.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagennodisponible);
            }



        }

    private void cargarImagenWebService(String rutaimagen , final UsuariosHolder holder) {
            String ip = context.getString(R.string.ip);
            String url = ip + "/DBRemota/"+ rutaimagen;
            url = url.replace(" " , "%20");

        ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                holder.imagen.setImageBitmap(response);
            }
        }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error al cargar la imagen..." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
       // request.add(imageRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(context).addToRequestQueue(imageRequest);
    }

    @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listaUsuarios.size();
        }



    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
            this.listener = listener;
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
            if (listener!=null){
                listener.onClick(view);
            }

    }

    public class UsuariosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView txtnombre,txtcategoria,txtdescripcion;
            ImageView imagen;

            public UsuariosHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                txtnombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
                txtcategoria= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtcategoria);
                txtdescripcion= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdescripcion);
                imagen = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);

            }
        }
    }
```

El problema es que cuando quiero hacer el patrón maestro detalle, no se como pasar la imagen

```
public class Listanegociodetalle extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView txnombre,txtdes,txthorario,txtdireccion;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listanegociodetalle);
        txnombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        txtdes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagendetalle);
        txthorario = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.horario);
        txtdireccion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.direccion);


        Bundle objeto = getIntent().getExtras();
        negocio Negocio = null;



        if (objeto!=null){
            Negocio = (negocio) objeto.getSerializable("negocio");
            txnombre.setText(Negocio.getNombre());
            txtdes.setText(Negocio.getDescripcion());
            txthorario.setText(Negocio.getHorario());
            txtdireccion.setText(Negocio.getHorario());
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar la imagen debes de pasarle un `int`, pero como esta en `String`, lo conviertes ("lo envuelves") así:

```
 imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(Negocio.getRutaimagen()));
```

Comment: Se para la aplicación dando el siguiente error en logcat:

(te edito la publicacion)

Comment: Te debe de dar el url completo: https  ://www.   .../images/citadella.jpg